# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present error when trying upload a file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload

I don't know how to solve the problem. Googled it for hours without success:

simple example:
**my form in jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="/asd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>    
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">    
</form>
```

my Controller's method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/asd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){    
        System.out.print(file);    
        return "string";    
    }
```

My context xml file

```
 <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

    </bean>
```

I have in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I even added allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" to every context.xml of my server as below:

```
<Context reloadable="true" allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
```

but the error still occurs and I don't know what I am doing wrong:

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message **Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present**
>
> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to
>   something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Add bellow filters in your web.xml file

Web.xml

```
<!-- Support for File Upload And Download -->
 <filter>
<display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
<filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
<filter- class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And also in your context file use filterMultipartResolver instead of multipartResolver because of Spring Security dependency as bellow

```
<!-- Support For File Upload And Download -->
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />

</bean>
```

And yes Cheerssssssss!!!!!!!!